# Combine PHP foreach loop with a SQL foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, loops, foreach

## Forward:

I've checked through the similarly worded questions on Stack Overflow but none are specific to what I'm attempting.

## What I have:

I have session data, two loops and a SQL table.

1. The first loop checks for specific existing session data and uses
   the keys (rather than the values) of this data to determine what ids
   should be selected (SQL) from a table.
2. The second loop outputs the SQL results row by row.

**...this can also be described in a less abstract and friendlier manner:**

1. The first loop looks for items currently added to the shopping cart
   (key = product id, value = quantity) to determine what products
   should be listed on "Your order" page.
2. The second loop list rows of data associated with each product id
   such as the title, description and unit cost.

## What I need:

Since my session data consists of products ids (keys) and a corresponding quantity (values) I need to show the quantity as part of each outputted row.

```
id                | title         | description   | unit cost     | amount             | subtotal
session data key  | from database | from database | from database | session data value | basic PHP math
(also in database)                                                                       (unit cost * amount)
```

## My code:

The first loop to use the session data keys to query the require products:

```
$id_from_session = "WHERE id = '9999999999'"; //fix due to not being sure how to simuataneously incorporate "WHERE" and "OR" into query loop (only looping the "OR" condition).

foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $key=>$value)
    {       
        $id_from_session .= "OR id ='".$key."'";
    }
```

The second loop to output the resulting rows of the query:

```
foreach ( $yourorders as $yourorder ) 
    {
    ?>
        <?php echo $yourorder->title; ?></br>
        <?php echo $yourorder->description; ?></br>
        <?php echo $yourorder->value; ?></br>
        <?php /* I NEED THE QUANTITY HERE */ ?></br>
        <?php /* VALUE * QUANTITY HERE */ ?></br>
    <?php
    }
<?php /* OVERALL TOTAL OUTSIDE OF LOOP */ ?></br>
```

## My question:

How do I incorporate the quantity from the session data loop (and the quantity * unit value) into the SQL results loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['post'][$yourorder->id]
```

should get you the quantity right? so,

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['post'][$yourorder->id]; ?>
```

or if short tags are allowed

```
<?= $_SESSION['post'][$yourorder->id]; ?>
```

Also a nicer way to build the WHERE string.

```
$where = array();
foreach($_SESSION['post'] as $key=>$value)
{       
    $where[] = "id ='".$key."'";
} 

$id_from_session = "WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $where);
```

Comment: Your solution for obtaining the quantity works and easily allowed me to calculate the subtotal (VALUE * QUANTITY). I'm currently reviewing your suggestion on the WHERE string and attempting to figure out how to achieve an overall total.

Comment: You could keep a running total in the foreach loop.

Comment: Your WHERE string solution works and yes, it's much nicer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, the running total inside the foreach loop worked. It was just a case of calling the running total variable outside of the loop to get the final total. The code for this can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/dE9dfNqv . Thanks for covering the three aspects of my question.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['post'][$yourorder->id] gives you the quantity since the keys are the product ids :)

well.. if you can be absolutely sure that your shopping cart keys don't need to be escaped you can write this:

```
$id_from_session = "WHERE id IN ('" . implode( "', '", array_keys($_SESSION['post']) ) . "')";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shapeshifter answered about 10 minutes earlier. Honestly not sure whether the id should be escaped. It originates from the name of the textbox rather than the value of the textbox. The value of the textbox represents the quantity. Is it best to escape both to be safe?

Comment: any data that comes from the browser (the user can change it) should be escaped or rather must be escaped